# How to combine values in the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following html:

```
<div class="topics">
  <span class="topic" data-value="hello">hello</span>
  <span class="topic" data-value="world">world</span>
  <span class="topic" data-value="one">one</span>
  <span class="topic" data-value="two">two</span>
  <span class="topic" data-value="six">six</span>
</div>
```

How to get value from each block and combine?
the result should be:

**["hello", "world", "one", "two", "six"]**

how can i achieve this ?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd get the spans and map back the text content

```js
var text = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.topics span'), function(elem) {
  return elem.textContent; // or elem.dataset.value for the data-attribute
});

console.log(text)
```

```html
<div class="topics">
  <span class="topic" data-value="hello">hello</span>
  <span class="topic" data-value="world">world</span>
  <span class="topic" data-value="one">one</span>
  <span class="topic" data-value="two">two</span>
  <span class="topic" data-value="six">six</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I think OP might be after `elem.dataset.value` instead of `textContent`

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem - maybe, they both contain the same thing, so hard to say

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [];
$("div span.topic").each(function(){
    arr.push($(this).text());    
});

console.log(arr);
```

If you would like to have in `jQuery`

http://jsfiddle.net/4egmewnv/

Comment: upvote for nice solution and thalaivar

Comment: Surely the selector should be `$('span.topic')`, and there's no jQ tag. The OP's question can be easily answered using vanillaJS

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: Yes, its easy in vaniall... there were some good answers.. thought of adding jQuery... seeming the OP is a newbee...

Comment: *"Unless another tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."* [tag:javascript]

Comment: @FelixKling: Is it wrong to answer in jQuery, there are other answers in javascript too...

Comment: @Thalaivar: Felix Kling wasn't stating something, he was _quoting_. No jQ tag means no jQ answers should be given. A bit of leniency is possible, but not too much. Personally, I think jQ is harmful for people who are still learning JS. There's a lot of horrible code written using jQ, it encourages bad practices and seems to fool people in to thinking JS is _not_ a functional language. It's rare to see people write `$(selector).on(event, callbackName);`, instead you often see `$(selector).on(event, function() { callbackName() });` Which is really bad practice

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using an HTML **`data-`** attribute to store the values you want in the array, the rest is easy.

Just create a **`for`** loop iterating over each element having the class **`.topic`** and push each **`data-value`** inside an array.

```js
/* ----- JavaScript ----- */
var
  array = [],
  els = document.querySelectorAll("span.topic");

for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) array.push(els[i].getAttribute("data-value"));

console.log(array);
```

```html
<!----- HTML ----->
<div class="topics">
  <span class="topic" data-value="hello">hello</span>
  <span class="topic" data-value="world">world</span>
  <span class="topic" data-value="one">one</span>
  <span class="topic" data-value="two">two</span>
  <span class="topic" data-value="six">six</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do with jquery:

```
$(".topics .topic").map(function() {
return $( this ).data("value");
```

})

Demo here:

https://fiddle.jshell.net/Flautarian/0n68ao7j/

Comment: *"Unless another tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."* [tag:javascript]

Comment: ok , lets do only with javascript then


`var words = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("topic"));
console.log(words.map(function(obj){return obj.dataset.value}))`

Demo here:

https://fiddle.jshell.net/Flautarian/0n68ao7j/1/